# Fields on images, displayed on edit page

Tags: entities, media, files

I'm trying to implement a way for users to add a "caption" and "credit" (name of the photographer) to photos which are attached to an article. The user should be able to upload an image and assign a caption and credit, preferably from the edit page for the article.

I've installed the media module and added "caption" and "credit" fields to the image file type, but I can't figure out where the user can edit those fields. Is there any way to show those fields somewhere on the edit page?

Answer (score 2):

I did similar with creating photo albums connected to a content type using the [field_collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. This way you can easily customise whats added very quickly as you are essentially creating a new type of entity (think of it as having an article entity and attaching a new photograph entity which has its own image, caption and credit fields).